# In which fileshould I write style sheet(less) in roots starter theme of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, less, starter-kits, roots-toolkit

I am new in **roots starter theme of wordpress**. In 'assets/less' folder, where should I write style sheet(There I found 4 files - _bootstrap.less,_global.less,main.less,_variables.less).Please anybody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main.less` is the file to edit.  The files with an `_` prefixed are either dynamically generated or are static libraries which should not be amended.

You should use `@import` within `main.less` to add in additional code.

Answer (score 0):

As you add more components and layouts to your theme, create new files for them and then add new @import's in main.less.